# Filter MS Access subreports based on calling form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have data that I want to summarize in a single report with six subreports:

- Potential sales by department
- Actual sales by department
- Potential sales by region
- Actual sales by region
- Potential sales by sales associate
- Actual sales by sales associate

Each of these shows the "by" (department, region, associate) in one column and the sales value in the second column. The report itself is unbound, but called by a form that I also use to call a detail report showing data for each individual sale. I want to be able to use many of the same filters (such as department, office location, range of sales dates, etc.) on the summary form that I use for filtering the details.

Because the subreports use GROUP BY, it's impossible to query them in such a way that I can include filter values in the Filter property. I would have to include them in the Record Source property.

My current attempt has been to pass the values from the form to fields on the report that I can reference in the queries of the subreports, but this doesn't seem to be working. I also tried passing a filter string to the report that I programmatically pass to the queries underlying the subreports, but the report won't take a filter string and I'm currently using OpenArgs to pass a custom value for the header of the report.

I'm not convinced this is the best way to solve my problem, so I'm open to alternative solutions so long as it gets me the same end product.

Comment: It sounds like the Record Source property is being set at design time, and you want to set it at Run time.  my old copy of Ken Getz sez that "the report's Open event runs before the query that supplies data for the report".  I believe that I have modified Record Source in a prior project and was able to set it at run time.  What are your thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you were referring to, but it did make me realize I should be putting the code in the subreport's Report_Open event instead of trying to manipulate the (still unloaded) subforms from the parent Report_Open event. Report_Load, as you noted, is too late to do anything, and you can't manipulate the subreports before they're loaded, so the only event that works is the subreport's Report_Open.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a PassThruQuery (ptq_mySummary) as a template and replace things at run time.

I use ptq because the display does not get wrapped into unreadability after I save it.  Also I can put in replaceable parms, e.g.  @geoLevel  and later retrieve it via

```
sSQL = QueryDefs(ptq_mySummary).SQL
sSQL = Replace(sSQL,"@geoLevel", me.arg...)
Me.RecordSource = sSQL
```

Replacable parameters can be anything, for instance

```
Where (  nz(Wait.WaitResultAction, '') ='@Res'   
  And       Wait.WaitPriority  IN  ('@Prty')
```

I also use it to change Prod/Test Servers, and DST12/DST13/DST14 yearly Databases

```
 From [ODBC;Driver=SQL Server;Server=@aServer;Database=@aDatabase;].dbo.STU
```

Give it a try.